# NowJs server different to web server

Tags: node.js, nowjs-sockets

I'm playing around with nodejs and specifically looking at nowjs

I've got now up and running on a server running node and I have a separate web server. I successfully have the node server returning the client script and I reference this on the web server. This returns a 200 response code and all looks well. However I get javascript errors telling me that 'now' is undefined. As far as I understand it the 'now' variable should be available via the client script but this doesn't seem to be the case. Does anyone know if this set-up is possible? So the set-up is similar to the below pseudo code

```
 //Server 1 node.com
 if(request.url === '/nowjs/now.js'){
      var file = 'path_to_clientlib/now.js';
  fs.readFile(file, function(e, data) {

        if (e) {
           throw e;
        }

         response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'});
          response.end(data);
}
```

and server.com

```
   <script src="/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="http://node.com/nowjs/now.js"></script> <!-- This is returned properly -->
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){

    now.receiveMessage = function(name, message){
      $("#messages").append("<br>" + name + ": " + message);
    }

   $("#send-button").click(function(){
     now.distributeMessage($("#text-input").val());
     $("#text-input").val("");
   });

   now.name = prompt("What's your name?", "");

   });
   </script>

  <div id="messages"></div>
  <input type="text" id="text-input">
  <input type="button" value="Send" id="send-button">
```

Straight away the console just returns 'now' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there are enough modules that provide static file serving support, but if you want to manually serve a file I would do it like this...

```
var mime = require('mime')   // Get mime type based on file extension. use "npm install mime"
  , util = require('util')
  , fs = require('fs');

function serveFile(filename, res) {
  var filePath = process.cwd() + filename;
  var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);

  res.writeHead(200, {
     'Content-Type':mime.lookup(filePath),
     'Content-Length':stat.size
  });

  var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

  return util.pump(readStream, res);
}

// Your code...
```

Or check out the module **node-static** on [NPM](http://search.npmjs.org/#/node-static) or [Github](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static)

About how to use NowJS ([from the docs](https://github.com/Flotype/now#readme))

On the server

```
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(function(req, response){ 

  // See code above how to serve static files...

});

httpServer.listen(8080);

var nowjs = require("now");
var everyone = nowjs.initialize(httpServer);

everyone.now.logStuff = function(msg){
  console.log(msg);
}
```

On the client

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/nowjs/now.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  now.ready(function(){
    // "Hello World!" will print on server
    now.logStuff("Hello World!");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, although the file serving could probably be done another way, that isn't really the issue I'm having. The javascript file gets served correctly, but 'now' is always undefined on the other website when the client-side script is in face returned correctly. Is it not possible to do this across domain?

Comment: @TommyBs Do you have nowInitialize available as a global function? Otherwise share a link to your version of nowjs.
Is it the same as this version? https://raw.github.com/Flotype/now/master/lib/client/now.js

Comment: @TommyBs If you read the source you will see that there is no 'now' variable added to the global scope. Only window.nowInitialize is added which is a function that needs a uri and options. See my update with the code from the nowjs docs...

Comment: @TommyBs If you look at the now.js file on the examples page you will see that the last line in that script file is. "window.now = nowInitialize("//nowjs.com:3000", {});" in http://nowjs.com:3000/nowjs/now.js

Comment: The server side does have the var everyone = nowjs.initialize(server);

everyone.now.distributeMessage = function(message){
  everyone.now.receiveMessage(this.now.name, message);
};

Comment: @TommyBs Do you have the latest version of now? Did you see the NowJS github page.

Comment: Hi,Yeah I have the latest version of now. I installed it via npm. I see what you mean about window.now though. I've been playing around, and now I'm getting issues with socket.io I'm not sure if it's the hosting, but I probably need to set-up the server differently as it doesn't seem to be loading the correct modules and files. Either that or I need another url path for socket.io